# What is the cause of flexion-induced muscle cramping?

Tags: muscle, cramps

Some muscles, especially the biceps femoris to the back of the upper leg and the biceps brachii opposite the elbow side of the upper arm, can be made to cramp by hard flexion, bending the leg at the knee or the arm at the elbow very hard for a second or two until a cramp is induced. In the case of the leg, the effect can be increased by pointing the toes. The cramp can then be completely or nearly completely alleviated by stretching the respective muscle to full extension.

What physiological effect explains this flexion-induced cramping?

Comment: I really hope you find an answer. Cramping in any form is still not understood as to cause, as far as I am aware.